Do you know the name of this True Crime TV series - Looking for the episode also
I'm looking for an episode of a TV series. All I have is the description and a few details. It's a true telling so no actors and I can't remember if it's an anchor interviewing like Paula Zahn or just them talking to the camera like the usuals on these series...

First, I saw about half of it back in either 2013-2014. It is an episode from one of the true crime networks, most likely Investigation Discovery (ID), but could def be on Oxygen, Lifetime, A&E, or maybe BIO or whatever it's called now. I have gone through Fatal Vows, Deadly Women, Scorned, Deadly Affairs, Betrayed etc, and no dice so far. 
It's set in the US, not sure the state.. it's about a couple that I believe are married, have 2 or 3 kids, the affected  victims/people are interviewing throughout the episode and telling the story as it's being acted out. So the plot is about this woman who is either a neighbor, friend staying with them, something along those lines. 
What was clear is that this was someone they knew and trusted. This woman has an attraction or obsession with the wives husband, and wants to be with him.. 
Then she tries unsuccessfully a few times to kill the wife/mom. I'm almost positive that she tried poisoning her food/drink, I remember the wife being sick. She messed with her vehicle, tried to cause an accident etc... 
Finally she does something so obvious and flips out so  it's apparent and the couple realizes what's going on and it all hits the fan. 
As far as I can recall nobody actually died, which makes for an interesting search as far as these shows go. 
The conclusion of the episode - The husband and wife are giving the final comments separately, the wife explains that she ended up leaving her husband because she did believe that he was involved and knew what was happening.. 
I don't remember why she thought this, but she felt that strong about it that she ended the relationship. 
The husband gets upset/teary eyed and says he's devastated that she left him and that he had nothing to do with it, he didn't know anything about why this woman tried to hurt or kill her and that he never cheated on her. 
Side note: I do not know if the show is 30 mins or an hour. 

That's all I've got. Wish I had more. I hope someone has an idea about what the series is called, which would be awesome enough.  If you happen to know the series and episode number even better!

OK. I have edited the question body and added relevant tags, but you might wanna give a more descriptive question title.

TV One Fatal Attraction is along those lines, currently in 6th season.

Can you remember anything about the law enforcement angle? Was it police, FBI, etc? Also, just to try and rule out a few series, was the investigation heavy on forensics?

There was no reference to the police/FBI that I can recall nor forensics. It's a tough one, I've been searching everywhere for a while now with no luck. Thanks for trying!
